# Exception using TRY CATCH in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Following is the procedure in which i am trying to catch the exception, if there is any in stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test( IN contextFilter TEXT)
   BEGIN TRY


  set  @sub_query = 'SELECT id from test_table';

   PREPARE stmt_query FROM @sub_query;
      SELECT @sub_query;
                EXECUTE stmt_query;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_query;

   END TRY //
   BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
  END CATCH

 DELIMITER ;
```

When i try to source the stored procedure , i am getting the following exception

```
source /home/test.sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5 in file: '/home/test.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'set  @sub_query = 'SELECT id from test_table';

   PREPARE stmt_query FROM @' at line 5
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 17 in file: '/home/test.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
' at line 1
```

Comment: You can use [13.6.7.5 SIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html).

Answer (score 6):

The post above helped me, but I still had to do some research on my own. In order to provide a complete example you can see below. This code will declare a handler for "catching" SQLExceptions and then exit if it occurs.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_TEST`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_TEST`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN 
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SELECT CONCAT(@p1, ':', @p2);
    END;

    SELECT FAKE_COLUMN FROM MY_TABLE;
END //

CALL SP_TEST;
```

This works in mySQL version 5.7 and hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

In mySql, there is no `try... catch` block like in Java. You can I handle errors through error handling?

**Syntax**

```
DECLARE handler_action HANDLER
    FOR condition_value [, condition_value] ...
    statement

handler_action:
    CONTINUE
  | EXIT
  | UNDO

condition_value:
    mysql_error_code
  | SQLSTATE [VALUE] sqlstate_value
  | condition_name
  | SQLWARNING
  | NOT FOUND
  | SQLEXCEPTION
```

The handler_action value indicates what action the handler takes after execution of the handler statement:

**CONTINUE**: Execution of the current program continues.

**EXIT**: Execution terminates for the BEGIN ... END compound statement in which the handler is declared. This is true even if the condition occurs in an inner block.

**UNDO**: Not supported.

For more info go to [Official](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) site

Comment: This is incorrect, there is TRY, CATCH in stored procedures in MS SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16